# Период времени Базовый или Базисный

Tags: терминология, синонимы

Как правильно называть период времени, по отношению к которому выполняется анализ изменения различных показателей, - базисным или базовым? Я нашла аналогичный вопрос про инжиниринг, но в ответах все увлеклись именно этим термином, а конкретики про базисный и базовый было мало. Какое именно прилагательное следует использовать по отношению к периоду времени?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Базовый и базисный - это синонимы, поэтому  в сочетаниях терминологического характера обычно выбирается один из вариантов. В данном случае чаще используется "базовый период времени", например:

БАЗОВЫЙ (БАЗИСНЫЙ) ПЕРИОД - в экономических прогнозах, плановых расчетах и экономической статистике период времени, с которым производится сравнение проектируемых или отчетных показателей (ВВП, прибыли и др.), какого-либо другого, обычно более позднего, периода.

Базовый период — (BASE PERIOD) период, используемый как точка отсчета при расчетах индекса изменения цен.

Но вот, для примера,  в книге знаменитых сатириков используется не очень понятный для простых людей "базис": "В открытые ворота с дощечкой «Базисный склад» въезжали трехтонные грузовики, нагруженные доверху кондиционными рогами и копытами".

Answer (score 1):

Как человек, непосредственно вынужденный неоднократно решать эту же проблему, вывел для себя следующую зависимость из наблюдений за использованием этих слов в экономической литературе. Если речь идет о том, что значение показателя в некоторый период берется за базу и все последующие величины этого показателя затем сравниваются со значением в этом периоде, то период обозначаю "базовым". Например, когда в национальной статистической службе считают дефлятор ВПП, то какой-то год принимают за базовый и затем некоторое время по отношению к нему рассчитывают сам дефлятор и реальный ВВП. Спустя, скажем, 10 лет базовый год расчета дефлятора могут поменять. Ну или если в той же статистике мы говорим о разнице между цепным и базисным индексами, то принятый за "базу" для расчета базисного индекса год я буду называть базовым, а не базисным. Потому что при расчете цепного индекса "база" будет "плавать" - он считается по отношению к предыдущему году, который я и назову базисным периодом.
Всё это крайне умозрительно и никак не претендует на гарантированно правильный ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, в данном случае "базовый" однозначнее: даже непосвящённому ясно, что сам период берется за основу для сопоставления показателей. "Базисный период" - менее доходчивое выражение: его можно трактовать и как период, имеющий отношение к чему-то внешнему, например, к экономическому "базису" (есть такой сложившийся термин, часто употребляемый без уточняющего определения наряду с "надстройкой"). Можно отвлечься на мысль: уж не пойдёт ли дальше речь о периодичности развития этого "экономического базиса"?